# Excel formulae not working in structured table protected cells for the first row instance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Structured `Table1`=

```
     A     B        C
    QTY  Price    QTY*Price
1    3     3      =A*B
2
3
```

Column `QTY` & `Price` are not locked
while Column `QTY*Price` is locked & hidden as it has a formula.

Problem:
When I enter `QTY` and `Price` for the first row instance the formula in column QTY*Price is not calculating. Seems to be frozen as sheet is protected.
I want to keep sheet protected btw.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the formula down the table A1*B1 etc, then select those cells right click, format cells, protection ensure locked (and hidden if you want to hide the formula) are ticked. Then repeat for the cells where you would enter the QTY and price and ensure locked/hidden are unchecked

Then protect the workbook and all will be well - any more probs let me know...

If this works please don't forget to Mark :)

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. Actually this is a data entry table in excel. Somehow the formula is not loaded because list rows is seen as 0 and when I enter data in price and QTY it is unable to update the formula.

Comment: I mean the option you provided is not applicable to my case

Comment: So when you put values into QTY and price the formula doesn't update it stays at 0? which

Comment: The only thing I can see in re-reading your question is that if the formula is A*B rather that A1*B1 then it won't work

Comment: Yes this is the problem. Because the QTY*PRICE cell is protected.
When unprotected it is working fine. BTW this only happens if this is the first row in the table